# CONNECT ERROR: Unknown resource type

Tags: downloader

We have a [Magento extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/8digits.html) which is compatible with Magento 1.7+. I would like to make it compatible with Magento 1.5 and later.

But installation does not work on Magento Connect Manager / downloader it gives following error on console

```
CONNECT ERROR : Unsupported resource type
```

I was able to install it manually

- download extension with [freegento.com](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php)
- unzip package
- copy Eightdigits_MarketingSuite/app to MAGENTO_HOME/app
- cd MAGENTO_HOME
- ./mage sync   (you need to make ./mage executable if it was not : chmod 750 mage)
- I have cleaned cache on Cache Management page of Magento admin dashboard
- I have logged out and logged in to Magento Admin (as there is bug on Magento, after new installation it keeps giving 404 for new menu item)
- I have refreshed Magento store page so I could see 8digits comments in page source

  <!-- 8digits Marketing Suite -->

Instead of manual installation, we would like to make the extension compatible with 1.5 too, and possible to install with Magento Connect Manager. Could you please help with the error?

**Update**

when I enabled log (System -> Configuration -> Developer -> Log), I saw these on system.log

`2014-07-31T20:08:58+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: fopen(): Filename cannot be empty  in /private/var/web/magento152/downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Package/Reader.php on line 119
2014-07-31T20:08:58+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: get_resource_type() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given  in /private/var/web/magento152/downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Package/Reader.php on line 140
2014-07-31T20:08:58+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given  in /private/var/web/magento152/downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Package/Reader.php on line 123`

ps: I get this error when I want to upload/install package file (Eightdigits_MarketingSuite-1.0.0.tgz)

I changed the method (Reader.php line 119) to

`protected function _readFile()
    {
        $data = '';
        if ($this->_file) {
        $handle = fopen($this->_file, 'r');
        try {
            $data = $this->_loadResource($handle);
        } catch (Mage_Exception $e) {
            fclose($handle);
            throw $e;
        }
        fclose($handle);
        }
        return $data;
    }`

When I tried upload again, now console printed out

```
CONNECT ERROR: Package file is invalid
Invalid package name, allowed: [a-zA-Z0-9_-] chars
Invalid version, should be like: x.x.x
Invalid stability
Invalid date, should be YYYY-DD-MM
Invalid channel URL
Empty authors section
Empty package contents section
```

this time system.log did not give any more logs on this issue... I assume it was not able to read package.xml file inside tgz file. I checked the package file and it has package.xml and looks like right. I have also tried package that was generated by Magento itself (using magento admin Package Extensions)

same environment if I try to install with Magento Connect, I get this error (now I cannot also install with Magento Connect, but today I installed at least on our test environment without problem)

```
CONNECT ERROR: Package 'Eightdigits_MarketingSuite' is invalid
Empty package contents section
```

Here also I do not get any error log on system.log file.

**Update 2**

I have created extension package from System -> Magento Connect -> Package Extensions on admin interfaces of Magento 1.9 and Magento 1.5.1 (a installation that I have integrated extension manually as described above). Both packages have resulted in same error when I try to upload to another Magento 1.5.1 installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem, which was my command to pack files. I was using "j" option with old habit (compress archive with bzip2)

```
  tar -cvjf Eightdigits_MarketingSuite-1.0.0.tgz *
```

when I used following command to pack, it just worked fine

```
  tar -cvf Eightdigits_MarketingSuite-1.0.0.tgz *
```

Comment: This answer solved my issue. I just needed to repack a extension I downloaded.

Answer (score 3):

You need to republish the extension using the appropriate settings, just as you did originally.

Comment: Today we also installed Magento 1.5.1 to Unix environment, and same extension key worked just fine. A friend of mine also tried same extension, and he said it also worked without any problem. but I will try your suggestion